# Pop-ups for a preview of raster images (.jpg,.tiff etc.) as they are while writing LaTeX code

Tags: graphics, floats, editors, preview

I usually have a lot of figures to comment in my latex document sometimes for me would be helpful have a look to the figures as they are (not a preview of the final formatted results) just a very fast thumbnail or a popup to remember how they look and check if I placed the right one in the right place.

I know that I can compile only a part of code but I'm searching for a faster trick. Are there any editors able to do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Like AUCTeX' [`preview-latex`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html)?

Comment: It works for raster images as .jpg .png? i will edit the question...

Comment: Do you mean images included with `\includegraphics`?  In that case the answer is "yes"

Comment: @giordano Yes! I mean photos and all that stuff...How can I do that?

Comment: The answer is yes, of course `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX' [`preview-latex`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html) has this feature

> [image]

TeXstudio also has inline preview (based on AUCTeX' package)

> [image]

And Kile as well

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot good answer +1! is there a Vim alternative too?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.

Comment: is there a similar thing in TeXmaker? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GM same answer as above.  AUCTeX, TeXstudio and Kile are the only editors I know which support inline preview.  Actually they are all based on the [`preview`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview) package, developed as part of the AUCTeX project.